# Comparison char to character string

Tags: shell

This is part of the fastq script I wrote. At the beginning of the script I read a file using a while loop.

```
while read Sequence_Name && read Sequence && read Quality_name && read Quality_sequence
```

the file is a made of batches of 4 lines (Sequence_name, Sequence, Quality_name, Quality_sequence)

something like that ;

```
@HWI-ST330:304:H045HADXX:1:1101:1162:2055
NAGAACTTGGCGGCGAATGGGCTGACCGCTTCCTCGTGCTTTACGGTATCGCCGCTCCCGATTCGCAGCGCATCGCCTTCTATCGCCTTCTTGACGAGTT
+
#1=DDFFFHHHGHIJJJJIJJJGEGGAFGBHHEHGFBFFDEDECDDA==CB@BDDDDD?;B-<CBDDD>BBBBDDB5<@DDDCDDB@-9ACDDDDB?B<?
```

this part is the part of the script giving me issue

```
iq=1
fastq="'!\"#$%&\'\(\)*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_\`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"

until  [ $iq -ge ${#Quality_sequence} ]
                 do
                  charSQ=$(expr substr $Quality_sequence $iq 1)
                  if [[ $fastq =~ $charSQ ]] ; then
                     let iq++
                    else
                    echo "invalide format sequence quality"
                   fi
                  done
```

The issue is that according to the input it does not do the jobs. for example

using this input :

```
@SRR1350630.9.1 HWUSI-EAS753_0012:8:1:3888:945 length=22
GAGGTAGTAGATTGTATAGTTA
+SRR1350630.9.1 HWUSI-EAS753_0012:8:1:3888:945 length=22
KKJJNH]NNNNNNN________
```

it does the job but with these inputs

```
@SRR1350630.9.1 HWUSI-EAS753_0012:8:1:3888:945 length=22
GAGGTAGTAGATTGTATAGTTA
+SRR1350630.9.1 HWUSI-EAS753_0012:8:1:3888:945 length=22
KKJJNH[NNNNNNN________ #replacing ] by [ give me opposite result

@HWI-ST330:304:H045HADXX:2:2111:20110:84312
GTCGAGGTGCCGTAAAGCACTAAATCGGAACCCTAAAGGGAGCCCCCGATTTAGAGCTTGACGGGGAAAGCCGGCGAACGTGGCGAGAAAGGAAGGGAAG
+
@@<FFFFDFFH>DEGFEGIJGJIJD9;CFCG;@;9?DDCD8AHGEF@84ADB?CD>3@CAACBBBDD@@@??90))5055(22-95<-5(:<ACBB@?8?
```

it does not since I get the message :

```
invalide format sequence quality
```

thanks a lot for helping me to find the reason why ??

Comment: Try quoting `"$charSQ"` in the if test? Also if you are trying to find out if any invalid characters are in the line you can do that without searching character-by-character with a much simpler (inverted) regular expression match. Just make a (negated `^`) character class out of the valid characters and test whether it matches the string or not.

Comment: Thanks Etan quoting "$charSQ" seems to have done the trick at least using my test file with only 50 lines.

Comment: The reason quoting works is because without it the character in `$charSQ` is interpreted as a regex. Quote it and it is treated as a literal string. But you should try my other suggestion as it will perform *much* better over large files/lines.

Comment: This loop is a bit odd.  If all you are doing is trying to validate that all the characters of `$Quality_sequence` are elements of the string `$fastq`, try `test "$(echo "$Quality_sequence" | tr -cd '[[:alnum:]][[:punct:]]\n')" = "$Quality_sequence"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting `"$charSQ"` in the if test?
The reason quoting works is because without it the character in `$charSQ` is interpreted as a regex. Quote it and it is treated as a literal string.
 – Etan Reisner